# Problema con valor que devuelve Ajax al enviar mail, aunque sea exitoso

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Planteo esta duda por sugerencia de @CamiloVasquez que me ha ayudado en otra pregunta.
Tengo un form que recoge algunos datos del usuario, y tiene la opción de enviarlo por mail vía Ajax. A continuación el código que procesa los datos para armar el mail.

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST["nombre"];
    $email = $_POST["correo"];
    $cantHab = $_POST["cantHab"];
    $cantAdu = $_POST["cantAdu"];
    $cantMen = $_POST["cantMen"];
    $edadesMenores = json_decode($_POST['edadesMenores']);
    $destino = $_POST["desti"];

    $EmailTo = "juan@gmail.com";
    $Subject = "Mail desde el Form";

// armo el cuerpo del mail
    $Body = "Nombre: ";
    $Body .= $name;
    $Body .= "<br>";
     ...

    $Body .= "Cantidad de Menores: ";
    $Body .= $cantMen;
    $Body .= "<br>";

 // Punto del PROBLEMA 
        if($cantMen > 0 ){
            echo ($Body .= "Edad Menor/es: <br>");
            foreach($edadesMenores as $key => $edad){
            echo( $Body .= echo $edad->menor . " = " . $edad->edad . "<br>" ;
                        }
            echo($Body .= "<br>");
        }
 //armo los encabezados
        $encabezados = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
        $encabezados .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
        ...
// envío el mail
        $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $encabezados);

        // redirecciono
        if ($success){
           echo "success";
        }else{
            echo "invalid";
        }

        ?>
```

La idea es que cuando no haya menores, no parezca el título "Edad Menor/es:". Y que si lo haga sí hay 1 o más menores para saber la edad de cada uno.

Ahora bien, los mails llegan perfectamente. Haya o no menores.
**Así llega cuando no hay menores**:
Nombre: Aguilera, Juan
Email: juan@gmail.com
Destino: MAR DEL PLATA 
Cantidad de Habitaciones: 1
Cantidad de Adultos: 2
Cantidad de Menores: 0

**Así cuando hay uno a más menores:**
Nombre: Aguilera, Juan
Email: juan@gmail.com
Destino: MAR DEL PLATA 
Cantidad de Habitaciones: 1
Cantidad de Adultos: 2
Cantidad de Menores: 2
Edad Menor/es: 
Menor1 = 2
Menor2 = 5

El punto central y que no estoy viendo es que, al ser exitoso el envío de mail me devuelve el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que solo aparece cuando la cantidad de menores es 0, si es mayor, envía el mail (o sea que sería exitoso el envío), pero este mensaje no parece.
Sospecho que estoy errando algo en el foreach, pero no lo veo.

Este es el código del ajax.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "procesa-simulador.php",
        data: {nombre: nombre, correo: correo, cantHab: cantHab, cantAdu: cantAdu, cantMen: cantMen,edadesMenores: JSON.stringify(edadesMenores), desti: desti},
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            }
            else {
                formError();
            }
        }
    });
}
function formSuccess(){
    $( "#msgSubmit" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
}
```

Comment: No entiendo exactamente lo que sucede. A ver: ¿el mensaje se envía siempre, haya o no  menores? ¿cierto? ¿El problema es que el mensaje que muestras en la imagen sólo se muestra cuando la cantidad de menores es `0`? Yo no veo en ninguna parte del código la parte en que muestras el contenido de la imagen, de ahí mi  confusión. Aparte de que empiezas comentado cosas que aparentemente funcionan en el código, lo cual hace que tu pregunta sea poco clara.

Comment: Traté de ponerlos en tema. La imagen es el form. Ahora edito y agrego el Ajax.

Comment: ¿Ponerlos en tema? No entiendo... Exactamente, ¿qué es lo que quieres cuando la cantidad de menores es `0`y qué es lo que quieres cuando la cantidad de menores sea mayor que `0`? El código que has mostrado evalúa esa posibilidad, agregando contenido al body del mensaje en caso de que haya menores y eso lo hace bien... no entiendo entonces cuál es el problema.

Comment: El problema es el cartel de "Su correo ha sido enviado". Solo aparece cuando menores es 0. Pero aunque lo envía cuando es 1 o más, el cartel   "Su correo ha sido enviado", no aparece

Comment: ¿Dónde está el paréntesis que cierra el primer `echo` del `foreach`?

Comment: Quita todos los echo dentro del `for`, te darán problemas al recuperar la respuesta del lado del cliente. Ponlo así: **`if($cantMen > 0 ){
            $Body .= "Edad Menor/es: <br>";
            foreach($edadesMenores as $key => $edad){
            $Body .= $edad->menor . " = " . $edad->edad . "<br>" ;
                        }
            $Body .= "<br>";
        }`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que las peticiones Ajax recuperan aquí:

```
   success : function(text){
```

todo lo que se diga (`echo`)  en el servidor.

Al tener un montón de `echo` dentro del `for`, que por lo demás no te sirven para nada nada en este caso... cuando el código entra en ese bucle, no está respondiendo solamente `success` al final, sino que está respondiendo lo que tienes en esos `echo`.

Entonces, cuando aquí evalúas:

```
        if (text == "success"){
            formSuccess();
```

`text` no es igual a `success` sino a todo lo que has puesto con `echo`, por lo tanto, la condición no se cumple.

#### Solución

Quitar todos los `echo` que tienes dentro del `for`:

```
 // Punto del PROBLEMA 
        if($cantMen > 0 ){
           $Body .= "Edad Menor/es: <br>";
            foreach($edadesMenores as $key => $edad){
                $Body .= $edad->menor . " = " . $edad->edad . "<br>" ;
            }
            $Body .= "<br>";
        }
```

Con eso debería funcionar.

Comment: Sí, A.Cedano, ese era el error. Disculpas por el mal planteo, soy bastante novato en este sitio.

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas solucionado. Estamos para ayudarnos aquí, mientras más clara es la pregunta, más rápida será la solución. Saludos.